# JSON.stringify is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express

**REMARK: I've been searching for an answer for 3 hours, do not mark this as a duplicate as no answer is available.**

I'm writing a simple API in Node.js using Express. When dealing with some of my front-end JS I use JSON.stringify() to convert my 'data' object into JSON. This is the function that does this:

```
function JSON(){

let radicando = document.getElementById("radicando-errore").value;
let iterazioni = document.getElementById("ripetizioni-babilonese").value;

const data = {
    radicando: radicando,
    iterazioni: iterazioni
};
var json = JSON.stringify(data);

const options = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: json
};

fetch("/", options);}
```

Basically I obtain the input from these two input boxes:

```
<input type="number" id="radicando-babilonese" placeholder="Radicando"> <br><br>
<input type="number" id="ripetizioni-babilonese" placeholder="Ripetizioni massime"> <br><br>
```

And then proceed to insert it into the 'data' object and stringify it. However, I get the following error in the Chrome console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: JSON.stringify is not a function
```

I've tried changing many things around. **I've even tried using several examples from Mozilla Developer Network and other StackOverflow answers but non onf them work.**
Could it be that I use 'let' and not 'const' for the data? Could the fetch() URL not be correct and so the error backtracks? The function I placed above is the only one in my JS file and the button that calls it is:

```
<button type="button" class="calcola" onclick="JSON()">Calcola!</button> <br><br>
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. I'll also append the app.js Express/Node.js file:

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const body = require("body-parser")

const app = express();
const PORT = 8080;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/public/html/index.html"));
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log("App listening on:${PORT}");
})
```

Comment: `JSON` (try it out yourself in console) is an [already existent native function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) in JS. - So basically don't name your function `JSON` if it actually does something completely different :D - perhaps `postData()` would better fit

Answer (score 2):

`JSON` (try it out yourself in console) is an [already existent native object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) in JS. - So basically don't name your function `JSON` if it actually does something completely different :D - perhaps `postData()` would better fit

Comment: Thank you! I had completely forgotten about the possibility of conflicting namespace. Fixed it and it works!

Comment: @Stroboscopio well yes - basically a typo - you're welcome

Answer (score 1):

On the first line your function name is JSON it might be causing issue, Try renaming it to something else.

Comment: Thank you! I had completely forgotten about the possibility of conflicting namespace. Fixed it and it works!